# Adding a comma at the end of each line wmic

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

I am trying to get a comma seperated list of printers my computer has access to. So far I have `@echo off & for /f "delims=" %i in ('wmic printer get name ^| findstr /v "Name"') do echo %i,` but for some reason it's replacing the first letter of each printer with a comma. Changing the %i, in the end is slightly better, not replacing the first letter with a comma but just adding one in front of the name of the printer instead. Though this is better this is not what I'm looking for because I want to get the output.

```
PrinterOne,
Printer2,
Printer3,
etc,
```

I'm pretty sure %i, should work, or am I wrong?

Side note I've had a working solution for months running

```
For /F "Tokens=1,* EOL=' Delims=," %%G In ('%%SystemRoot%%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Printer Get Name^ /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("%%H") Do @Echo %%I,
```

from a batch file, but as it looks it does not work with some of the computers on our system. Could be windows related but I'm not sure.

Comment: `wmic` has that ugly line feed `CRCRLF` instead of just `CRLF`, so the first `CR` is kept as part of the variable (CR = Carriage Return = "goto the beginning of the line"). The second `for` loop in your working code strips the lone `CR`

Answer (score 0):

I managed this with

```
powershell -Command "& { Get-Printer -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | foreach-object {$_ + ','}}"
```